# Pandas subtract series by iloc, not by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `pd.Series`:

```
>>> a = pd.Series([1,2,3],index=[1,2,3])
>>> b = pd.Series([2,3,4],index=[2,3,4])
```

I would like to subtract these two series according to the elements' `.iloc`, not the index, and then get back the index of the first (or second, I don't care, really) `Series`.

Desired output:

```
>>> a - b
1    -1
2    -1
3    -1
dtype: float64
```

What actually comes out is:

```
>>> a - b
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this via accessing `numpy` array representation:

```
res = pd.Series(a.values - b.values, index=a.index)

print(res)

# 1   -1
# 2   -1
# 3   -1
# dtype: int64
```

Comment: Isn't that simply `a - b.values`?

Comment: @DSM, that would work as well. I did it this way so that OP can easily flip between using `a.index` and `b.index`, since this is the only "moving part".

Comment: @Scott, I'm well aware of that :).

Comment: @jpp: that seems like a lot of characters to put in for an easy flip, given that we could just use `a.values - b` instead, but YMMV..

Comment: Sometimes I like to be verbose :). Of course you're right. Please do post the alternative, ah I see pir has already.

Answer (score 3):

[@DSM's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862092/pandas-subtract-series-by-iloc-not-by-index/49862212#comment86739374_49862126) is what I recommend.
However, I'll show how you can do this in place for `pandas.Series`

```
a.values[:] -= b.values
a

1   -1
2   -1
3   -1
dtype: int64
```

You can also do the the same thing with:

```
a.loc[:] -= b.values
```

Or

```
a.iloc[:] -= b.values
```

Using `loc` or `iloc` are more idiomatic Pandas.

Comment: Agreed about @DSM's comment.  I have accepted the answer that contains his comment for that reason.